# Cocos2d tiled map add sprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, z-order

In the isometric tiled map z-ordering example for cocos2d-iphone, they use an object that is already in the tilemap as the player sprite, which is rendered as moving through the trees.

Is there a way to use a random `CCNode`, created though code (not in the tmx file, and not part of the sprite sheet), and have it z-ordered correctly with the tilemap? addChild is not supported on a `CCTMXLayer`, and the gives an error when using that reads:`'addChild: is not supported on CCTMXLayer. Instead use setTileGID:at:/tileAt:'`.

There's got to be a way to have a `CCNode` (let's say a simple `CCSprite`) z-order correctly with a tilemap, either using cocos2d's API, or some z-buffer technique. Any pointers?

Answer (score 3):

The CCTMXLayer doesn't support adding tiles at runtime because it's implemented with all sprites on a single spritesheet.  Because of this implementation detail you also can't call setTexture on an individual tile.

The easiest solution would be to have the sprite you want to use on the spritesheet at the beginning.  If you can't do this because it's generated at runtime or something, the next best thing (without touching cocos2d code) would be to modify the spritesheet.

Put a dummy tile in the spritesheet you're using for the TMXLayer and then, once you have the image you want to use, write it to the spritesheet using CCRenderTexture or something and use the newly generated Texture as your TMXLayer's texture.

You could also modify the CCTMXLayer to allow for your functionality but it sounds like you want to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add a tile to say tile (x,y) ( (x,y) in Tiled Map editor coordinates ) then use the following code -

myTileMap is the reference to the CCTMXTiledMap object.

```
CCTMXLayer *layer=[myTileMap layerNamed:@"yourlayer"];
NSAssert(floorLayer !=nil, @"Ground layer not found!");    
CGPoint tileAddPosition = [layer positionAt: CGPointMake(x,y)];

//Create your CCNode or CCSprite or whatever...say object name is **tileToBeAdded**

tileToBeAdded.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
tileToBeAdded.position = tileAddPosition;
[myTileMap addChild:addedTile z:1];
```